# Spring Kafka - Subscribe new topics during runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I'm using the annotation `@KafkaListener` to consume topics on my application. My issue is that if I create a new topic in kafka but my consumer is already running, it seems the consumer will not pick up the new topic, even if it matches with the `topicPattern` I'm using. Is there a way to "refresh" the subscribed topics periodically, so that new topics are picked up and rebalanced upon my running consumers?

I'm using Spring Kafka 1.2.2 with Kafka 0.10.2.0.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't dynamically add topics at runtime; you have to stop/start the container to start listening to new topics.

You can `@Autowire` the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` and stop/start listeners by `id`.

You can also stop/start all listeners by calling `stop()`/`start()` on the registry itself.

Comment: Awesome! It works for topics! Does the same logic apply to new partitions on a topic or Spring Kafka catches those in runtime?

Comment: Yes; it will work; all topic assignment is done by the broker; the container just subscribes and gets whatever the broker assigns to it.

Comment: @GaryRussell what about already existing partitions? i.e. in `KafkaListener` I subscribe to a selected partition of a topic, but then in runtime I want to subscribe to another one that already existed - is it possible to do without listeners restart?

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is possible.

It worked for me with Kafka 1.1.1.

Under the hood Spring uses `consumer.subscribe(topicPattern)` and now it is totally depends on Kafka lib whether the message will be seen by consumer.

There is consumer config property called `metadata.max.age.ms` which is 5 mins by default. It basically controls how often client will go to broker for the updates, meaning new topics will not be seen by consumer for up to 5 minutes. You can decrease this value (e.g. 20 seconds) and should see KafkaListener started to pick messages from new topics quicker.

Comment: Using Kafka 1.1.0 also worked. I applied it to my Kafka config file like this:
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG, 5000); which set the refresh time to 5seconds. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following way works well for me.

```
ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties("topic1", "topic2");
KafkaMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String> container = createContainer(containerProps);
containerProps.setMessageListener(new MessageListener<Integer, String>() {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> message) {
        logger.info("received: " + message);
    }

});
container.setBeanName("testAuto");
container.start();
```

ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/

In practical application, I use a `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` instead of single-threaded `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`.

Comment: what is `createContainer(containerProps)`