# Kafka consumer picking up topics dynamically

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka consumer configured in Spring Boot. Here's the config class:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:kafka.properties"})
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, GenericData.Record> consumerFactory() {

        dataRiverProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("bootstrap.servers"));
        dataRiverProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, env.getProperty("group.id"));
        dataRiverProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, env.getProperty("enable.auto.commit"));
        dataRiverProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("auto.commit.interval.ms"));
        dataRiverProps.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("session.timeout.ms"));
        dataRiverProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, env.getProperty("auto.offset.reset"));

        dataRiverProps.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, env.getProperty("schema.registry.url"));
        dataRiverProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
        dataRiverProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(dataRiverProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericData.Record> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericData.Record> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

And here's the consumer:

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

    @Autowired
    private MessageProcessor messageProcessor;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.topics}'.split(',')}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consumeAvro(GenericData.Record message) {
        messageProcessor.process();
    }

}
```

Please note that I am using **topics = "#{'${kafka.topics}'.split(',')}"** to pick up the topics from a properties file.
And this is what my kafka.properties file looks like:

```
kafka.topics=pwdChange,pwdCreation
bootstrap.servers=aaa.bbb.com:37900
group.id=pwdManagement
enable.auto.commit=true
auto.commit.interval.ms=1000
session.timeout.ms=30000
schema.registry.url=http://aaa.bbb.com:37800
```

Now if I am to add a new topic to the subscription, say pwdExpire, and modify the prop files as follows:

```
kafka.topics=pwdChange,pwdCreation,pwdExpire
```

Is there a way for my consumer to start subscribe to this new topic without restarting the server?
I have found this post [Spring Kafka - Subscribe new topics during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142205/spring-kafka-subscribe-new-topics-during-runtime), but the documentation has this to say about **metadata.max.age.ms**:

> The period of time in milliseconds after which we force a refresh of
>   metadata even if we haven't seen any partition leadership changes to
>   proactively discover any new brokers or partitions.

Sounds to me it won't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Some more information: I have a scheduled task that runs every 5 minutes to check the DB. So if we add some control value in the DB, is there a way to force the program to fetch from the properties file and consume accordingly again? Thanks!

Comment: you could look at spring cloud config and use the annotation @refreshscope.  I am not sure if this would work with the configuration annotated classes though.

Comment: So basically you can combine the spring config @ refresh and this link on reinitializeing the spring beans for the producer and consumer factory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218086/how-to-reinitialize-a-spring-bean
that might work for you

Comment: I don't think refresh scope will work here; AFAIK, refresh scope only works with passive beans; the listener container is an active component (implements `SmartLifecycle` and is started/stopped by the application context.

Comment: I don't have the app running on spring cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; the only way to do that is to use a topic pattern; as new topics are added (that match the pattern), the broker will add them to the subscription, after 5 minutes, by default.

You can, however, add new listener container(s) for the new topic(s) at runtime.

Another option would be to load the `@KafkaListener` bean in a child application context and re-create the context each time the topic(s) change.

**EDIT**

See the javadocs for `KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Pattern pattern)`...

```
/**
 * Subscribe to all topics matching specified pattern to get dynamically assigned partitions.
 * The pattern matching will be done periodically against topics existing at the time of check.
 * <p>
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Are there examples that I can refer too?

Comment: @GaryRussell would you mind adding an example of pattern matching.  Also to clarify I guess what you are saying is once a topic is created on the brokers as long as it matchs the pattern that the consumer is looking for then it pick it up every 5 minutes.  This 5 minute timer is that a configurable property that's set by default on the consumer factory.

Comment: @Matt See the `topicPattern` property on `@KafkaListener`; it's a regex e.g. `pwd.*` for all topics starting with `pwd`. The 5 minutes is the default `metadata.max.age.ms` which is a consumer property (see the kafka documentation). `The period of time in milliseconds after which we force a refresh of metadata even if we haven't seen any partition leadership changes to proactively discover any new brokers or partitions.` @Hua an example of which option?

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell I am interested in Option 1. Just checked the API of KafkaListener, and honestly I don't see much difference between "topics" and "topicPattern".  
For "topics" -- The topics for this listener. The entries can be 'topic name', 'property-placeholder keys' or 'expressions'. An expression must be resolved to the topic name.
For "topicPattern" -- The topic pattern for this listener. The entries can be 'topic name', 'property-placeholder keys' or 'expressions'. An expression must be resolved to the topic pattern.

Comment: Yes, the javadocs there need some improvement; they assume you are familiar with the Kafka APIs. See the javadocs for `KafkaConsumer.subscribe()` instead - I added them to the answer.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks!