# spring kafka @KafkaListener listener container?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

Is there a way to get hold on the ListenerContainer object used by @KafkaListener? I want to dynamically subscribe to new topics using the container if possible. Or there is another better way to subscribe new topics at runtime? Thanks. -aj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use '@EnableKafka', then  KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry is automatically registered as Bean ( code :  https://git.io/JfQDQ )

So you can get a list of listener as below.

```
@Service
public class KafkaListenerHandler {
    private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;
    public KafkaListenerHandler(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        this.registry = registry;
    }
    public List<MessageListenerContainer> getListener() {
        return new ArrayList<>(registry.getListenerContainers());
    }
}
```

However, you cannot change the topic during Runtime...

See this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54467119/2462408

Comment: thanks, @bistro. Any other way to update the topic list in existing listener container?

Comment: I don't know such a way.  Kafka Consumer does not originally have that function.

In other ways, create a new listener, or declare the topic name regular pattern